# Is there a (gui) tool for creating Qt Help Project files?

Tags: qt

We are using Microsofts HtmlHelp with .chm-files at the moment, but newer projects use Qt as the GUI framework instead of MFC.

Edit: This documentation is for the end users of the software and explains how to use the software, so it's mainly text with a few tables and screenshot strewn in. It also has an index that you can search.

Since our help documentation writers already know how to write .html-files, I thought it would be easy enough to switch to Qt Help, but I'm getting stuck on how to make creation of the neccessary .qhp- and .qhcp-files easy enough for them. They have a GUI tool that helps them connect their .html-files and images and stylesheet and compile everything into .chm-files.

My research: I googled a bit and found that the documentation people could continue creating their .chm-files and I could then convert those with the QtHelpConverter from this site https://www.helpandmanual.com/qt-help.html
That seems like a very roundabout way though ...

**Question:** Is there a tool, preferably with gui, that helps you organize multiple .html-Files, images, stylesheet etc into .qhp- and .qhcp-files?

Comment: A question that pops up is: is this documentation of only the interface / routines or only textual information or a combination of both?

Comment: @albert This documentation is for the end users of the software and explains how to use the software, so it's mainly text with a few tables and screenshot strewn in. It also has an index that you can search.

Comment: In that case I would not directly go for just HTML files, but more for a documentation system like Serna or docbook and from there generate the different output formats like HTML / PDF etc.

Comment: The problem isn't to generate the HTML files, it's to link them together in the .qhp and .qhpc files that qhelpgenerator wants. These are xml-files that reference the HTML files. They contain the table of contents and which page should show up when you search for specific keywords, and also a list of all the files that should go into the final, compiled help file that QtHelpEngine wants.

Comment: I know that doxygen can create the qhp file (and with doxygen one cn input besides code also a.o. markdown files that are converted to html. The entire doxygen manual is generated by the doxygen program), maybe this is something for you. About the `qhpc` file (or did you mean `qhcp`)  I have no information. Disclaimer I never ran the qhelpgenerator (yet), so I don't know how the output will look like.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into doing it with doxygen.